# JavaFX: Set actual height of vbox children

Tags: java, javafx, vbox

I have a VBox pane and a few tableviews inside. When the window height is too small to show all tables in full size, they are minimized. But I want to see my tableviews in its actual size with a scrollbar, if required.

Comment: Ever tried using a `ScrollPane` wrapping your `VBox`?

Comment: No, i have add scrollbar as element of hbox. So my hbox contains vbox(with a few tableviews) and scrollbar.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to go ahead and try and wrap your content inside a `ScrollPane` instead of reinventing the Wheel.

Comment: please "accept" my answer below, so this question gets recognized as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness:

The solution is to wrap the content inside a [`ScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) which automatically manages the scrolling if the content inside grows or shrinks.